# Exact string match on Solr.text_general

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

I have following string indexed into solr.

```
<doc>
<field name="key">book self</field> </doc>
<doc>
<field name="key">bookself</field> </doc>
<doc>
<field name="key">my book self</field> </doc>
```

When my query string have the word key:"book self" then i should only get first doc as result not the first and third document. Same when i search for 
key:"self" it should return empty document.

Please tell me how i can achieve above.

Comment: chnage the fieldType to string from text_genereal for the field key

Answer (score 4):

If you need an exact match, you should use `string` instead of `text_general`. If, for whatever reason, you do actually need `text_general` for this document, use `<copyField/>` to generate a 2nd field that has type `string` and which you then use for the exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Change the field Type to string.

Make sure you have the below entry

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored.

Then change the field type for the field key.

```
<field name="key" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: solr core's autogenerated managedschema.xml file already have a fieldtype string, without the attribute omitNorms="true", Please tell me what is the role of attribute  omitNorms.

Comment: omitNorms : set to true to omit the norms associated with this field (this disables length normalization and index-time boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.